# How to add a Custom Button in Contact Standard Page

Tags: custom-button, page-layout, contact

How can i add a Custom Button in Contact Standard Page like the Pic belows shows
or where can i get the Default Contact Pagelayout to rebuild it ?

Thanks for Help!

[image: Custom Button in Contact Standard Page like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: add a custom button to Contact object by Setup -> Contact -> Buttons, Links, and Actions -> New

Step 2: go to contacts tab and click edit layout link and add your button to page layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setup>Customize>Page layouts>Click on Edit beside Page layout>Select the Buttons>Drag and drop to the Layout>Click Save.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answers are pretty old for 2022... So let's refresh a lil' bit:

**Setup > SObject to modify (ie: Account, opportunity, etc) > Page layouts >** Then click **"Page Layout"**

[image: Object manager image.]

---

**Now click on the layout to be modified:**

[image: Page layout view.]

---

Now in the **left side** of the tool panel that shows up, **click on "button", and drag and drop.**

[image: Drag n' fun!]

---

Isn't that easy?

Answer (score 0):

Click 
Setup>Customize>Page layouts>Click on Edit in front of Page Layout you on which you want to add the button.

From the top floating bar
go to the left pane and click Buttons .

Now on the right hand side you will see the button you created earlier Drag and drop that button downwards on the Layout

Click Save.